# How to sum one-to-one polymorphic relationship column through hasMany relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relationship

How to sum one-to-one polymorphic relationship column through hasMany relationship in Laravel?

Owner model

```
public function capitals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Capital');
}
```

Capital model

```
public function transaction()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Transaction', 'transacable');
}
```

Transaction model

```
public function transacable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I want the owner to have-many transactions through capital, something like this:

Owner model

```
public function transactions()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Transaction', 'App\Capital', 'transacable_id')->where('transacable_type', 'App\Capital');
}
```

But I cannot get a relationship to work. and get this error.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'capitals.transacable_id' in
>   'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `transacable_id` in the right position:

```php
public function transactions()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Transaction',
            'App\Capital',
            'owner_id', // Foreign key on capitals table...
            'transacable_id', // Foreign key on transactions table...
            'id', // Local key on owners table...
            'id' // Local key on capitals table...
        )->where('transacable_type', 'App\Capital');
}
```